How can i fix the Jython no named module error
Im trying to use java gui in intellij to make a login screen for a instagram scrapper program ran on a python file. However, i need to run the python file from java and so i'm using Jython to try and run the program. But i am getting a error.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named instaloader
If anybody has any suggestions or different approach to my problem please let me know
String username = usernameField.getText();
String password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());

PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

pythonInterpreter.set("username", username);
pythonInterpreter.set("password", password);

pythonInterpreter.exec("import instaloader\n" +
                        "import pandas as pd\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "def main(username, password):\n" +
                        "    bot = instaloader.Instaloader()\n" +
                        "    bot.login(user=username, passwd=password)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, username)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # Getting the usernames of all followers\n" +
                        "    followers = [follower.username for follower in profile.get_followers()]\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # if followers[0][0] == '0':\n" +
                        "    #     followers[0] = followers[0][1:]\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    followers_df = pd.DataFrame(followers)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # Storing the results in a CSV file\n" +
                        "    followers_df.to_csv('followers.csv', index=False)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # Retrieving the usernames of all followings\n" +
                        "    followings = [followee.username for followee in profile.get_followees()]\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # if followings[0][0] == '0':\n" +
                        "    # followings[0] = followings[0][1:]\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    followings_df = pd.DataFrame(followings)\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    # Storing the results in a CSV file\n" +
                        "    followings_df.to_csv('followings.csv', index=False)");

This is the same thing but in a python file and easier to read
import instaloader
import pandas as pd

def main(username, password):
    bot = instaloader.Instaloader()
    bot.login(user=username, passwd=password)

    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, username)

    # Getting the usernames of all followers
    followers = [follower.username for follower in profile.get_followers()]

    followers_df = pd.DataFrame(followers)

    # Storing the results in a CSV file
    followers_df.to_csv('followers.csv', index=False)

    # Retrieving the usernames of all followings
    followings = [followee.username for followee in profile.get_followees()]

    followings_df = pd.DataFrame(followings)

    # Storing the results in a CSV file
    followings_df.to_csv('followings.csv', index=False)

I need to execute a python file from java

How did you install instaloader to the Jython interpreter?

Your Jython environment does not share modules with CPython environments in your system (nor do CPython environments ordinarily share with each other).  If you want a module in Jython that is not bundled with it then you need to install it, into Jython.

I just edited the code for the actual error i had in java my apologies
